# Change Default Functionality Of 'One' Model In One-To-Many Relationship In Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a one-to-many relationship.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPES, max_length=255, default='student')

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='students', default=None, null=True)
```

When I go into Student in Django Admin I have a dropdown box and can select their Teacher. This is good. However, when I go into Teacher, instead of a dropbox of Students, I get an 'Add Another User' button with a dropdown list of all Users. Clicking a student and pressing 'Save' throws the following error

```
Student with this User already exists.
```

How can I remove 'Add Another User' from the Teacher page and replace it with a dropdown list of all Students (or Students who havent been assigned a Teacher)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> when I go into Teacher, instead of a dropbox of Students, I get an
> 'Add Another User' button with a dropdown list of all Users.

Yes, that is correct because the student variable name isn't available for use in the Teacher class’s field. If you define classes being referred to at the top, you need to use a string (for example, 'Student'); however, the foreign key is only defined on one side of the relationship.

One of the options that you could use is `ManyToManyField`, you would have three classes, and one of the classes uses the `through` field. You need to define self-referential ForeignKeys by defining hierarchical structures, in the User class, use the string `self.`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you :)

Comment: np read about it here, there are some restrictions on (using M2M) the intermediate model. (page:90 or section: 3.2 Models and databases) https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/django/latest/django.pdf